# Why didn't people care about the whereabouts of this character in Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* after all superheroes return with Infinity Stones from their respective timelines, we see that Hawkeye returns with the Soul Stone and Rhodes returns with thr Power Stone.

Here Nebula and Natasha fail to return. Everyone is so depressed and concerned about Natasha but no one gives a damn about Nebula. She spent five years with the Avengers team helping them. Even if the Avengers don't care for her, at least they should've inquired about her since it's a potential threat to the Avengers' plan.

What am I missing here?

Comment: To clarify - you mean when they return on the platform thing, right? Nebula's returned is a bit "delayed"? (I think I remember something like that)

Comment: I'm pretty sure 2014-Nebula is standing next to Rhodey on the platform when everyone (except Natasha) returns. Why would she be late? It's a time machine. Even if she leaves Morag hours or even days after Rhodey, the return point in 2023 is the same.

Comment: Nebula does return and she returns at the same time as everyone else.

Comment: The quantum GPS devices that everyone wore are synced so that everyone would arrive at the same moment. So regardless of how long each mission took, they all came back to the same moment. Otherwise you'd have seen some people who finished their mission fast wandering around waiting for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Nebula does not fail to return.**

I just watched the movie again, and remembered this question during the scenes addressed by it; the sequence of events is as follows:

Rhodey and 2023 Nebula both move to activate their Time GPS and return, but at the moment Rhodey hits his, 2023 Nebula freezes up due to the intermingling of her neural network with 2014 Nebula's. She does not have a chance to activate her GPS, and as Rhodey has already activated his, he never witnesses this.

2014 Nebula takes the Time GPS, Pym Particles, and gold-toned plates from 2023 Nebula's face. She uses the gold plates to disguise herself as 2023 Nebula, and hands over the Pym Particles to 2014 Thanos (presumably for him to replicate them).

**2014 Nebula then appears on the platform at the exact same time as the others**, with the exception of Natasha. There is no delay at all on her return, she looks exactly like the Nebula who left so they have no reason to question her, and as everyone is concerned with the loss of Natasha they take no notice of any behavioral flags.

**To the eyes of everyone present, the Nebula who left is the Nebula who returned, and they are given no reason to suspect that she is someone different.** This is even emphasized later, when 2014 Nebula takes the gauntlet from Clint, who says, "Hey, I know you." Even after 2014 Thanos attacked, they still had no reason to suspect the Nebulas had traded places.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what movie you have seen but **Nebula does return**.

But it's the 2014 Nebula, not the 2023 Nebula.

Comment: I think OP meant that NEbula arrived a bit later, after the others were mourning Natasha. I don't remember quite well but that seemed strange to me as well

Comment: @Jenayah I don't think it was that delayed, or the others would have noticed, as they noticed with Natasha. 1,2 seconds max...

Comment: I also seem to remember her arriving later and separate from everyone else; not being in the scene where they all simultaneously arrive. I'll keep an eye out for this when I see it again in a few days.

Comment: Nebula arrives with the rest of the team, it's time travel to that exact moment, there is no need for her to return later. What she does do later is tinker around with the computer to allow for Thanos to arrive.

Comment: Just finished second viewing. Confirmed that she arrived back in the platform with everyone at the exact same time. Dunno why I mis-saw it the first time.

Answer (score 7):

**Nebula does return**

Nebula does return with the avengers, albeit not the Nebula they think. My memory is a bit hazy, but even if she was delayed slightly there's one other key difference:

Clint is there to say that Natasha didn't make it and won't be making it. Nebula they don't know about because the last War Machine saw, she was about to return as well.

Answer (score 2):

A Nebula does return, but it's not the one from 2023 who was part of the Avengers team.

It's the Nebula that belonged to 2014, who was still loyal to Thanos.

Comment: I think OP meant that NEbula arrived a bit later, after the others were mourning Natasha. I don't remember quite well but that seemed strange to me as well

Comment: Two times "went/travelled back" makes this answer difficult to read. You should clarify the directions.